# How to generate dense rank in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to generate Rank similar function works like `DENSE_RANK()` in database product (such as `SQL Server`).

Here is sample data :

```
Col1 
1
2
3
4
4
```

So, i want to be generate following sequence.

```
Col1  sequence
1      4
2      3
3      2 
4      1 
4      1
```

As of now i have use `rank()` function. But, it doesn't work as i expect.

```
=RANK(A1,A1:A5, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula UNIQUE:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1<=UNIQUE(A:A)))
```

[image]

---

If not we can create the unique list with this:

```
INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($A$1:$A$5,A:A,0)=ROW($A$1:$A$5),ROW($A$1:$A$5)*{1,1})))))
```

this makes the whole formula an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter when exiting edit mode.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1<=INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($A$1:$A$5,A:A,0)=ROW($A$1:$A$5),ROW($A$1:$A$5)*{1,1})))))))
```

[image]